# Can't access popups content in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a problem with accessing popups content.
Here is popup class in .py:

```
class LicencePopup(Popup):

    def dismiss_popup(self, *args):
        self.dismiss()

    def submit_licence(self):
        # print self.content.ids.licence_field.text
        # print self.ids.licence_field.text
        # print self.content.ids[licence_field].text
```

Popup in .kv look like this:

```
<LicencePopup>:
    size_hint: .3, .35
    title: 'Enter license key'
    separator_height: 0
    title_size: 35
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: license_field
            multiline: False
            text: "59353-58506-87377-00410"
            font_size: 24
        Label:
            id: license_label
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.dismiss_popup()
            Button:
                text: "Submit"
                on_release: root.submit_licence()
```

My problem is how to get text from TextInput(id: licence_field).
I have tried a few things(commented prints) but I can't get this working.
Can you please help with this?

Comment: Perhaps more help will come if you provide a [mcve]

Comment: You have a typo error. Replace `licence_field` with `license_field`. e.g. `print self.ids.license_field.text`.

Comment: What a shame... Thank You